# How to specify cookbook path in .kitchen.yml file for chef_solo provisioner?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, test-kitchen

I want to specify cookbook paths using chef_solo as a provisioner in Test Kitchen.  We are not using Berkshelf or chef_zero at this time.

I set cookbooks_path in my .kitchen.yml file, but it seems like the chef_solo provisioner ignores that flag.  See stack trace, below.

.kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  require_chef_omnibus: 11.8.0
  roles_path: '../../roles'
  data_bags_path: '../../data_bags'
  environments_path: '../../environments'
  cookbooks_path: '../cookbooks, ../../site-cookbooks'
```

Stack trace:

```
$ kitchen converge analytics-centos-65
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.2.1)
-----> Converging <analytics-centos-65>...
       Preparing files for transfer
       Resolving cookbook dependencies with Berkshelf 3.2.1...
       Removing non-cookbook files before transfer
       Preparing data bags
       Preparing environments
       Preparing roles
       Transfering files to <analytics-centos-65>
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
       Starting Chef Client, version 11.8.0
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.8.0 ***
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 4294
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["role[default]", "role[test]", "role[development]", "role[etl]", "role[ets]", "role[log_consolidator]"] from JSON
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] INFO: Run List is [role[default], role[test], role[development], role[etl], role[ets], role[log_consolidator]]
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [sysctl::attribute_driver, yum::epel, ad-summos::timezone, ad-summos::ntpd, ad-summos::users, ad-summos::pgpass, ad-summos::fix_adsummos_dir_permissions, ad-summos::ec2-keys, ad-summos::sudo, ad-summos::aws, ad-summos::git, ad-summos::bashrc, ad-summos::setup-additional-adsummos-directories, ad-summos::aws-adsummos-user, ad-summos::denyhosts, ad-summos::p7zip, ad-summos::set_firewall_rules, ad-summos::system-tools, ad-summos::deploy_analytics_code, vsftpd, users::development, ad-summos::setup_hostname, etl::configure_etl, ad-summos::mysql-client, ad-summos::postgresql-devel, etl::pdi-tools-42, etl::create_etl_folders, etl::system-wide-rvm-permissions, etl::user_agent_utils, etl::pgpass-adsummos-user, ets::ets-install, ets::varnish-install, ets::sftp-user, ad-summos::sinatra, log_consolidator::configure_log_consolidator, log_consolidator::log_cron_crontab, log_consolidator::install_consolidator_packages]
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for analytics-centos-65
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
       Compiling Cookbooks...
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
       Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook sysctl not found. If you're loading sysctl from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
       [2015-01-07T18:07:06+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
>>>>>> Converge failed on instance <analytics-centos-65>.
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/analytics-centos-65.log for more details
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: SSH exited (1) for command: [sudo -E chef-solo --config /tmp/kitchen/solo.rb --json-attributes /tmp/kitchen/dna.json  --log_level info]
>>>>>> ----------------------
```

**Related to:** [How to specify cookbook path in .kitchen.yml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367855/how-to-specify-cookbook-path-in-kitchen-yml-file/23375031#23375031)

I see **sethvargo**'s answer for provisioning with chef_zero, but we're blocked on Chef Zero because a solid number of our environments and roles are configured in Ruby, not JSON.  https://github.com/opscode/chef-zero/issues/107.  Likewise, Berkshelf is an iteration or two ahead of where we are in our code migration atm.

Is there a way to specify local cookbook paths with the chef_solo provisioner?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't speak for it's place in the yaml. However I was able to get it working using a line in the knife.rb

Sounds right to me, but remember that [config.rb](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb.html) takes precedence now, since Chef Client 12.0.

The docs do well to describe this, but keep in mind the attributes that the others have described:

Default config.rb Location:

```
~/.chef/config.rb
```

cookbook path syntax:

> cookbook_path ["/full/path/to/repo/cookbooks"]

And reload Chef to test.

Answer (score 0):

It should be an array in Yaml:

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  require_chef_omnibus: 11.8.0
  roles_path: '../../roles'
  data_bags_path: '../../data_bags'
  environments_path: '../../environments'
  cookbooks_path:
    - ../cookbooks
    - ../../site-cookbooks
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid yaml.  I think it's `-` instead of `*` but even doing this I can't get test-kitchen to see custom paths.  I am using chef_zero.  I've been trying to get anything to work.  Can't understand until at least one success.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for it's place in the yaml. However I was able to get it working using a line in the knife.rb

cookbook_path            ["/full/path/to/repo/cookbooks"]

using this in the knife.rb of the repo where I was running kitchen allowed it to work.